# Stray lines when using overlays in tikz-uml

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays, tikz-uml

I show a UML diagram in my slides and I want to put some notes into an overlay. When I do this,the connecting lines appear from the beginning. How do I get rid of them?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \umlemptyclass{Class}
        \visible<2>{\umlnote[x=5]{Class}{Lorem Ipsum etc}}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `\onslide<>` rather than `\visible<>`.

Comment: @cfr No difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `\only<>` instead of `\visible<>` did the trick.